# How to cross compile Paho-MQTT-C library for ARM?

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, mqtt, yocto, paho

How to for cross compiling Paho-MQTT C library for ARM platform.

Here are the steps I followed.

```
1) Downloaded library from  [Paho-MQTT-C][1]
2) after download, I opened the directory and entered some commands.
3) command for setting the GCC-ARM tool chain (environment variable_path)
4) make CC=(ARM-CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
```

Next, I observe following error

```
mkdir -p build/output/samples
mkdir -p build/output/test
echo OSTYPE is Linux
OSTYPE is Linux
sed -e "s/@CLIENT_VERSION@/1.2.0/g" -e "s/@BUILD_TIMESTAMP@/Mon Apr 16 17:13:10 IST 2018/g" src/VersionInfo.h.in > build/VersionInfo.h
arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -fPIC  -Os -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -Ibuild -o build/output/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0 src/MQTTPersistence.c src/Heap.c src/Socket.c src/MQTTProtocolClient.c src/MQTTProtocolOut.c src/StackTrace.c src/MQTTPersistenceDefault.c src/MQTTClient.c src/Messages.c src/MQTTPacketOut.c src/Clients.c src/OsWrapper.c src/Thread.c src/MQTTPacket.c src/Log.c src/LinkedList.c src/utf-8.c src/SocketBuffer.c src/Tree.c  -shared -Wl,-init,MQTTClient_init -lpthread -Wl,-soname,libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
ln -s libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0  build/output/libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
ln -s libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1 build/output/libpaho-mqtt3c.so
arm-cortexa9-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -fPIC  -Os -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -Ibuild -o build/output/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0 src/MQTTPersistence.c src/Heap.c src/Socket.c src/SSLSocket.c src/MQTTProtocolClient.c src/MQTTProtocolOut.c src/StackTrace.c src/MQTTPersistenceDefault.c src/MQTTClient.c src/Messages.c src/MQTTPacketOut.c src/Clients.c src/OsWrapper.c src/Thread.c src/MQTTPacket.c src/Log.c src/LinkedList.c src/utf-8.c src/SocketBuffer.c src/Tree.c -DOPENSSL  -shared -Wl,--start-group -lpthread -ldl -lssl -lcrypto -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-init,MQTTClient_init -Wl,-soname,libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1 -Wl,-no-whole-archive
In file included from src/MQTTPersistence.h:23:0,
             from src/MQTTPersistence.c:28:
src/Clients.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/Socket.c:32:0:
src/SocketBuffer.h:28:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/SSLSocket.c:31:0:
src/SocketBuffer.h:28:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/MQTTPacket.h:25:0,
             from src/MQTTProtocolClient.h:25,
             from src/MQTTProtocolClient.c:34:
src/SSLSocket.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/MQTTPacket.h:25:0,
             from src/MQTTProtocolOut.h:24,
             from src/MQTTProtocolOut.c:35:
src/SSLSocket.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/StackTrace.c:21:0:
src/Clients.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/MQTTPersistence.h:23:0,
             from src/MQTTClient.c:53:
src/Clients.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/MQTTPacket.h:25:0,
             from src/MQTTPacketOut.h:22,
             from src/MQTTPacketOut.c:29:
src/SSLSocket.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/Clients.c:24:0:
src/Clients.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/MQTTPacket.h:25:0,
             from src/MQTTPacket.c:26:
src/SSLSocket.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/MQTTPacket.h:25:0,
             from src/Log.c:27:
src/SSLSocket.h:29:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
In file included from src/SocketBuffer.c:25:0:
src/SocketBuffer.h:28:25: fatal error: openssl/ssl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:219: recipe for target 'build/output/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0' failed
make: *** [build/output/libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0] Error 1
```

4)  I installed openssl using this command

> $ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev*

Openssl installed successfully, but still getting the same above error.

What I have to do for compiling Paho-MQTT-C library for ARM?

Comment: hum, why do you even want to manually crosscompile it?there is an OpenEmbedded recipe ready for you to use at http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-oe/recipes-connectivity/paho-mqtt-c/paho-mqtt-c_1.2.0.bb (as your tags suggest that you want to run "yocto", e.g. the OE based poky distribution)

Comment: actually Yocto is already installed on my board, here i am trying to cross-compile my (C-based) project for ARM. I am using Paho-C library for MQTT connection ,which is internally uses openssl/ssl.h file for their operation. @LetoThe2nd

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution given your question and explanation as in the comments is as follows:

1. Rebuild the image on your board and have it include the paho-mqtt-c package. This can be done through the IMAGE_INSTALL variable in an image recipe, or CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL if you want to inject it through local.conf or such.
2. For cross-compiling, generate a fitting SDK: bitbake -c populate_sdk YOUR_IMAGE
3. Use that built sdk to compile your software. This is documented here in chapters 8 and 9 extensively: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-using-the-standard-sdk

Optionally, you can also do:

1. Create a recipe for your application and build it directly through bitbake. Have the recipe DEPENDS += "paho-mqtt-c", then everything should be taken care of automatically.
2. For development purposes, you can build from your live development source tree as described here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#building-software-from-an-external-source

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using a Yocto based build then you may consider integrating the layer [meta-intel-iot-middleware](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel-iot-middleware)

The meta-intel-iot-middleware layer provides an usable recipe for [paho-mqtt 3.1](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-intel-iot-middleware/tree/recipes-connectivity/paho-mqtt?h=master-linear). You can include this using IMAGE_INSTALL.